# How does lme4 calculate residual variance for an LMM?

Tags: variance, lme4-nlme, residuals, model, glmm

How does the `lmer()` function calculate residual variance for an LMM? If I code a model and then try to manually calculate residuals, the variance of the manually calculated residuals is much smaller than the variance reported by R.

```
mod<-lmer(response~predictor + (1|id), data= dat)
summary(mod)

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 visit_individual (Intercept) 562.0    23.71   
 Residual                     352.9    18.79   
Number of obs: 960, groups:  visit_individual, 370

pred<-predict(mod)
res<-dat$response-pred
var(res)

[1] 245.1599
```

Comment: The pure model error excludes the id-level random effect, and the 359.2 is the MLE of that error variance. The residual you are calculating includes both the pure error and the id-level random effect.

Comment: How can I isolate the id-level random effect?